# How can I show Icons next to each with the remaining drop down?

Tags: css

I've got a dropdown Icon(pumkin 1) div which is pushing away all other icons. The reason for that, it has a dropdown which I need to overlay the text at the bottom.

I need to show all icons next to each other(1,2,3,4) with the remaining behaviour of dropdown(Where I click first Icon and it shows dropdown).

What is wrong in my css?

```css
.header-bar__top {
  height: 3.5rem;
  background-color: greenyellow;
  z-index: 100;
  /* box-shadow: $header-bar-shadow; */
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.header-bar__container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  max-width: 1152px;
}

.header-bar__container:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down {
  display: inline;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button {
  color: black;
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  float: right;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button:focus
  + .header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  margin-top: 13px;
  height: 4.25rem;
  background-color: orange;
  display: inline-flex;
  opacity: 1;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-bar-utility {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
  color: pink;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header-bar-utility__icon {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.header-bar {
  height: 3.5rem;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.header-bar__toggle-menu {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 1rem 0 0.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  min-width: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./test.css" />
    <title>Dropdown</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header-bar">
      <div class="header-bar__top">
        <div class="header-bar__container">
          <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down">
            <button
              class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button"
              tabindex="1"
            >
               1
            </button>
            <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item">
              This is a dropdown place
            </div>
          </div>

          <button :class="header-bar-utility">
            <div class="header-bar-utility__icon"> 2</div>
          </button>

          <button :class="header-bar-utility">
            <div class="header-bar-utility__icon"> 3</div>
          </button>

          <button class="header-bar__toggle-menu"> 4</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h1>Text overlayed</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I change some of your code. Not only the first icon button but also need to change the 4th icon button's HTML. I also moved the dropdown area from the button area to the outside. I also Add javascript code to show or hide the dropdown.

Html part -

```
<body>
<div class="header-bar">
  <div class="header-bar__top">
    <div class="header-bar__container">
    
      <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down">
        <button
          class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button"
          tabindex="1"
        >
           1
        </button>
      </div>
      
      <div style="display: flex">
       <button :class="header-bar-utility">
        <div class="header-bar-utility__icon"> 2</div>
      </button>
      <button :class="header-bar-utility">
        <div class="header-bar-utility__icon"> 3</div>
      </button>
      <button class="header-bar__toggle-menu"> 4</button>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

            <div class="header-bar-mobile-drop-down__item">
          This is a dropdown place
        </div>

<h1>Text overlayed</h1>
</body>
```

Js part -

```
var firstBtn = document.querySelector('.header-bar-mobile-drop-down__icon-button');

firstBtn.addEventListener('focusin', toggleClass);
firstBtn.addEventListener('focusout', toggleClass);

function toggleClass() {
 const a = 
   document.querySelector('.header-bar-mobile-drop- 
   down__item').classList.toggle('header-bar-mobile-drop- 
   down__item_dropdown');
 }
```

Full code - https://jsfiddle.net/alimurrazi/17wevh0t/3/